# What is the purpose/benefit of Session::registerBag()?

Tags: session, laravel

Laravel's Session Facade has methods for dealing with Bags in addition to simple attributes (see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L501). What kind of use case showcases when bags would be useful? I'm trying to figure out why they exist and what benefit they offer to my application.... maybe I should be using them?

Is it just a way of managing a collection of something within the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session bags are generally used to avoid namespace polution/collision in the global session namespace -- that is, by default Laravel lets any programmer read/write to the session

```
Session::set('key','value');
Session::get('key');
```

In a large application -- especially an application with a large number of globally disparate developers (i.e. any project that uses multiple packages from different sources) the ability to separate the session out into namespace helps different packages claim different keys for a session. Instead each package (or application) can claim a uniquely named "session bag", and then name variables within the bag however they want.

Also, [in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html), session bags aid in the testing of session variables, as the application accesses the session purely via an abstraction instead of a via the `$_SESSION` super global.  Session bags are less important to Laravel in this case, as Laravel completely side steps PHP's internal session handling.